# Clojure - Why does into behave differently with a list than a vector?

Tags: clojure

Why does `into` behave differently when the collection being inserted into is different? For example:

```
user=> (into [] [1 2 3])
[1 2 3]
```

So far, so good. Exactly as I would expect. However:

```
user=> (into () [1 2 3])
(3 2 1)
```

Why does this reverse the arguments? I assume it's for performance, and the items are inserted sequentially with `cons`? This still seems to break the abstraction to me, in two differently typed ordered collections I would expect the result to be ordered consistently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`into` is `conj` and `seq` together.

conj adds to lists at the beginning, and vectors at the end for efficiency so that there is no traversal of either type in order to add to it.

This is explained nicely in [Programming Clojure](http://www.clojurebook.com/) when talking about the Collection abstraction in Clojure:

> These functions (conj/seq/count/empty/=) are all polymorphic with
>   regard to the concrete type of collection being operated upon. Said
>   another way, each operation provides semantics consistent with the
>   constraints of each data structure implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to @MarkFisher 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20314684/2608009): `into` is analogous to `reduce conj` ; the difference of behaviour of `into` follows from the difference in behaviour of `conj` :

```
(conj '(:b :c) :a)             ;; '(:a :b :c)      ;; prepend to lists
(conj  [:a :b] :c)             ;; [:a :b :c]       ;; append to vectors

(conj #{:a :b}    :c)          ;; #{:a :b :c}      ;; add to sets
(conj #{:a :b :c} :c)          ;; #{:a :b :c}      ;; nothing if already there

(conj {:a 1 :b 2}      [:c 3]) ;; {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} ;; add key-value
(conj {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} [:c 4]) ;; {:a 1 :b 2 :c 4} ;; replace value if present
```

**EDIT:** I recently used `conj` 's polymorphism at my advantage. Writing a palindrome generator, the same function could be used to generate both head and tail of the palindrome, simply by feeding either a vector or a list.